# Django & Django REST Framework - Adding @decorator_from_middleware(MyMiddleware) to API class based view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-decorators

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to utilise the `@decorator_from_middleware` from Django decorators with a class based Dango REST Framework view on a per action basis:

e.g., something like this:

```
@decorator_from_middleware(MyMiddleware)
def retrieve(self, request, uuid=None, *args, **kwargs):
   ...
```

I can't see anything in the Django REST Framework documents that allows this to be achieved. I assume it may have to be applied as some sort of class `Mixin`?

Comment: Can you brief the use-case? Probably there may be a better way to do the things

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I need to log view statistics on the retrieval of a particular resource...

Comment: I would also like to know if this is possiable as I have my own middleware that I would like to use with DRF class views